# Multiprocessing with TypeScript + playwright

Tags: typescript, deployment, multiprocessing, playwright, react-typescript

Recently, I developed a web application using React that communicates with a Flask server and launches a script in a separate process using multiprocessing. This process triggers a browser controlled by Selenium with parameters I've set (URL, product category, etc.).

This is how the communication looks::
Frontend:

```
  const handleNewSearchTextSubmit = async (
      event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>,
   ) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const searchText = event.currentTarget.searchText.value;
      const lowPrice = event.currentTarget.lowPrice.value;
      const highPrice = event.currentTarget.highPrice.value;
      if (searchText === "" && links.length === 0) {
         alert("Please enter search text or select category");
         return;
      }

      try {
         await axios
            .post(`${URL}/start-scraper`, {
               search_text: searchText,
               low_price: lowPrice,
               high_price: highPrice,
               url: links,
            })
            .then((response) => {
               if (response.status === 200) {
                  console.log(response.data.pid);
                  setBotsData((prev) => [
                     ...prev,
                     {
                        search_text: searchText,
                        low_price: lowPrice,
                        high_price: highPrice,
                        pid: String(response.data.pid),
                     },
                  ]);
               }
            });

         alert("Scraper started successfully");
      } catch (error: any) {
         alert("Error starting scraper:" + error.message);
      }
   };
```

Backend

```
@app.route('/start-scraper', methods=['POST'])
def start_scraper():
    logging.info(request.json)
    url = request.json.get('url')
    search_text = request.json.get('search_text')
    low_price = request.json.get('low_price')
    high_price = request.json.get('high_price')

    pause_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    kill_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    p = Process(target=main, args=(url, search_text, low_price, high_price, pause_event, kill_event))
    p.start()
    botsDict[str(p.pid)] = Bot(p, pause_event, kill_event)

    response = {'message': 'Scraper started successfully', 'pid': p.pid}
    return jsonify(response), 200
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar using TypeScript and Playwright?

Comment: Do you know if playwright is better antidetect framework than selenium?